# procedimiento almacenado sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedure, busqueda

El objetivo es realizar un store procedure que consulte todos los recursos, pero aplicando de uno a cinco filtros en el input, es decir, el usuario puede buscar por nombre, hashtag, clave, nombre de tipo de recurso, nombre de área de conocimiento,

Tengo el siguiente diagrama:

[image: esta es la relación de mis tablas, ya implemente el store y si funciona en los filtros que pertenecen a la tabla recurso, pero ahora quiero que también funcione en la tabla tipo de recurso y área de conocimiento]

Este es mi código:

```
USE SIRH

--Si ya existe el procedimiento almacenado se descarta
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE TYPE = 'P' AND NAME='SPBuscarRecurso')
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPBuscarRecurso];
    PRINT 'El procedimiento almacenado [dbo].[SPBuscarRecurso] se elimino correctamente';
END

--Si no existe, entonces se crea 
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPBuscarRecurso]
(@cClave VARCHAR(MAX), @cNombre varchar(max), @cHashtag VARCHAR(MAX),
@cNombreAreaConocimiento VARCHAR(MAX), @cNombreTipoRecurso VARCHAR (MAX))
WITH 
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

         --Se verifica que la variable nombre no este vacia
        IF(@cNombre != '' or @cClave != '' or @cHashtag != '' or @cNombreTipoRecurso != '' or @cNombreAreaConocimiento != '') --si es asi, entonces hace la consulta 
        BEGIN

             SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tbl_Recurso  join       --se hace el join con la tabla tipo de recurso y Area de conocimiento
             tblCat_TipoRecurso on tblCat_TipoRecurso.cNombre LIKE 
             '%'+  @cNombreTipoRecurso +'%' join        --se compara el nombre con valor del parametro que recibe
             tblCat_AreaConocimiento on tblCat_AreaConocimiento.cNombre LIKE
             '%'+ @cNombreAreaConocimiento + '%' where
             tbl_Recurso.iIdTipoRecurso = tblCat_TipoRecurso.iIdTipoRecurso and 
             tbl_Recurso.iIdAreaConocimiento = tblCat_AreaConocimiento.iIdAreaConocimiento or
                (tbl_Recurso.cNombre LIKE '%'+ @cNombre +'%' ) or
                (tbl_Recurso.cClave Like '%' + @cClave + '%') or
                (tbl_Recurso.cHashtag LIKE'%'+  @cHashtag + '%')

        END

        Else begin

        PRINT 'Registros no encontrados'

END
--Si todo esta correcto se hace el commit
COMMIT TRANSACTION
PRINT 'Transaccion realizada con exito'

END TRY

--EXcepciones y control de errores
BEGIN CATCH
   DECLARE @Error_Number int, @Error_Severity int, @Error_State int,
        @Error_Procedure varchar(1000), @Error_Line int, @Error_Message varchar(8000)
    SELECT
        @Error_Number = ERROR_NUMBER(),
        @Error_Severity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @Error_State = ERROR_STATE(),
        @Error_Procedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
        @Error_Line = ERROR_LINE(),
        @Error_Message = ERROR_MESSAGE()

    RAISERROR(@Error_Message,@Error_Severity, @Error_State) 

    PRINT 'Ha ocorrido un error. No se realizo la transacción'

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

END CATCH
GO
 PRINT 'El procedimiento almacenado [dbo].[SPBuscarRecurso] fue creado correctamente';
```

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta en si?

Comment: que al ejecutar el SP no funciona la consulta ya que si uno es vacio, me trae todos los registros, cosa que esta mal, deberia respetarme si solo le inserto un solo filtro, por ejemplo "nombre" y los demas quedan vacios, deberia traerme los registros que coinciden con ese nombre

Comment: Lo que pienso que podrias hacer es volverlo SQL Dinamico para que si llega lo pongas y si no pues no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas aquí. Estás confundiendo las clausulas del WHERE con las del JOIN, por lo que están invertidas. También estás usando varchar(max), lo cual es seguro pero lento. Siempre debes usar el tipo de dato adecuado. Tu consulta es por si "contienen" algún valor, lo cual hará lenta la consulta porque nunca podrá usar índices. Por último, necesitas mejorar las condiciones para poder obtener sólo las filas (no registros) que cumplen con alguna condición.

```
USE SIRH

--Si ya existe el procedimiento almacenado se descarta
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE TYPE = 'P' AND NAME='SPBuscarRecurso')
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPBuscarRecurso];
    PRINT 'El procedimiento almacenado [dbo].[SPBuscarRecurso] se elimino correctamente';
END

--Si no existe, entonces se crea 
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPBuscarRecurso]
(@cClave VARCHAR(MAX), @cNombre varchar(max), @cHashtag VARCHAR(MAX),
@cNombreAreaConocimiento VARCHAR(MAX), @cNombreTipoRecurso VARCHAR (MAX))
WITH 
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    --Se verifica que la variable nombre no este vacia
    IF(@cNombre != '' or @cClave != '' or @cHashtag != '' or @cNombreTipoRecurso != '' or @cNombreAreaConocimiento != '') --si es asi, entonces hace la consulta 
    BEGIN

        SELECT DISTINCT * 
        FROM  tbl_Recurso               r
        JOIN  tblCat_TipoRecurso        tr ON r.idTipoRecurso       = tr.IdTipoRecurso
        JOIN  tblCat_AreaConocimiento   ac ON r.iIdAreaConocimiento = ac.iIdAreaConocimiento
        WHERE (r.cNombre  LIKE '%' + @cNombre +'%'                  OR @cNombre                 IS NULL OR @cNombre                 = '')
        AND   (r.cClave   LIKE '%' + @cClave + '%'                  OR @cClave                  IS NULL OR @cClave                  = '')
        AND   (r.cHashtag LIKE '%' + @cHashtag + '%'                OR @cHashtag                IS NULL OR @cHashtag                = '')
        AND   (tr.cNombre LIKE '%' + @cNombreTipoRecurso +'%'       OR @cNombreTipoRecurso      IS NULL OR @cNombreTipoRecurso      = '')
        AND   (ac.cNombre LIKE '%' + @cNombreAreaConocimiento +'%'  OR @cNombreAreaConocimiento IS NULL OR @cNombreAreaConocimiento = '')
        OPTION(RECOMPILE);
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Registros no encontrados';
    END

    --Si todo esta correcto se hace el commit
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    PRINT 'Transaccion realizada con exito';

END TRY

--EXcepciones y control de errores
BEGIN CATCH
   DECLARE @Error_Number int, @Error_Severity int, @Error_State int,
        @Error_Procedure varchar(1000), @Error_Line int, @Error_Message varchar(8000)
    SELECT
        @Error_Number = ERROR_NUMBER(),
        @Error_Severity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @Error_State = ERROR_STATE(),
        @Error_Procedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
        @Error_Line = ERROR_LINE(),
        @Error_Message = ERROR_MESSAGE()

    RAISERROR(@Error_Message,@Error_Severity, @Error_State) 

    PRINT 'Ha ocorrido un error. No se realizo la transacción'

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

END CATCH
GO
 PRINT 'El procedimiento almacenado [dbo].[SPBuscarRecurso] fue creado correctamente';
```

Comment: Luis Gonzales gracias, si me funciono

Comment: ¿Y entiendes cuál era la falla y cuál fue la solución?

Comment: si, igual me di cuenta que estaba poniendo OR en lugar de AND, lo que ocasionaba que se cicle mis registros y la consulta no funcione de manera adecuada

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te faltan los paréntesis

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tbl_Recurso
join tblCat_TipoRecurso on tblCat_TipoRecurso.cNombre LIKE '%'+  @cNombreTipoRecurso %' join
tblCat_AreaConocimiento on tblCat_AreaConocimiento.cNombre LIKE %'+ @cNombreAreaConocimiento + '%' 
where tbl_Recurso.iIdTipoRecurso = tblCat_TipoRecurso.iIdTipoRecurso and 
tbl_Recurso.iIdAreaConocimiento = tblCat_AreaConocimiento.iIdAreaConocimiento 
or (
    (tbl_Recurso.cNombre LIKE '%'+ @cNombre +'%' ) or
    (tbl_Recurso.cClave Like '%' + @cClave + '%') or
    (tbl_Recurso.cHashtag LIKE'%'+  @cHashtag + '%')
)
```

Comment: ejecutar el SP: use SIRH

 EXECUTE dbo.SPBuscarRecurso cClave ='',cNombre ='Test',cHashtag = '', cNombreAreaConocimiento = '', cNombreTipoRecurso= ''
 todos los campos estan vacios excepto el nombre, pero no lo respeta y me duplica o triplica los datos

Answer (score 0):

El problema es como estás planteando los `LIKE`, por ejemplo:

```
tbl_Recurso.cNombre LIKE '%'+ @cNombre +'%'
```

¿Que ocurre cuando `@cNombre = ''`? algo como esto:

```
tbl_Recurso.cNombre LIKE '%%'
```

Lo que le dice a la base, "traeme todas las filas". Si quieres resolverlo con `''` como bandera de ignorar el filtro, lo que en realidad deberías hacer, es algo como esto:

```
(@cNombre <> '' and tbl_Recurso.cNombre LIKE '%'+ @cNombre +'%')
```

Es decir, si el parámetro no es blanco, hacemos el `LIKE` sino se invalida el filtro. Esto funciona por que la conexión entre filtros es un `OR`, no olvidar los paréntesis que encierran el `and`. Este patrón es el que deberías usar en todos los demás filtros de tu consulta